# How to make a set of Views and Controller in root Area available to another Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a section in the root area of our .NET MVC website called Email
so we have:

```
/Views/Email/<all the views>

/Controllers/EmailController
```

I now want to make this section available within another area called Administration. This would include using the EmailController in the root area rather than creating a new one in the Administration Area.

What is the cleanest/best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From your Administration area you can call the EmailController any time.

```
Return RedirectToAction("ViewName","Email");
```

In that case the email controller return the view related to the Email action.

Is it ok or or you want more?

Comment: This probably would have been a step in the right direction but in the end my problems were due to using a subdomain to reference the area instead of a directory. i.e. administration.domain.com instead of domain.com/administration/